# How do you expand $\frac{d}{df(x,y)}$ in terms of $\frac{d}{dx}$ and $\frac{d}{dy}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Basically the title, but I'll provide an example in case I haven't worded clearly.
Say I have $$\frac{d}{d(x^{2}+y^{2})}$$, how can I obtain an expression that is equivalent to this in terms of $\frac{d}{dx}$ and $\frac{d}{dy}$?
Don't really know where to start. Thanks for any help

edit: I've realised my question might not make sense, so I'll try and contextualise it more.
I have a function  $f(x,y)$, which I've shown can be expressed as
a function of $z=x^{2}+y^{2}$, $f(x,y)=\widetilde{f}(z)$. This function appears in a PDE. Is there a way I can express the following term
$$\left(\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}}+\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial y^{2}}\right)\widetilde{f}(z)$$ In terms of $\widetilde{f}(z)$ and $\frac{d}{dz}$?

Comment: An expression such as $\frac{dg}{df}$ or $\frac{\partial g}{\partial f}$ makes sense in two contexts: 1. $\frac{dg}{df}$ is the derivative of the inverse function of $f(g)$ (this doesn't apply to your example). 2. $\frac{\partial g}{\partial f}$ is a partial derivative of $g$ that might depend on $f$ and on other variables. Can you apply the chain rule to $g(x,y,f(x,y))$ ?

Comment: I've edited the question to make it more specific to the example I'm trying to solve, does this make sense now?

Comment: The first step would be the chain rule applied to $\partial_x\tilde{f}(x^2+y^2)=\tilde{f}'(x^2+y^2)2x$. And so on. Can get clumsy but is straightforward. In that *particular* example however it is worth looking at the Laplace operator in polar coordinates.